# ViewAppeared not called on Android, but on iOS

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a `MvvmCross` app targeting Android and iOS. I have used the template available on VS Marketplace. For some reason, it seems my view model's `ViewAppeared` is never invoked on Android, though I can see that the constructor of the view model is executed. Also, the corresponding page to the view model is constructed. On my iOS app, this works fine. Where should I be looking?

Comment: Can you show us some code? It would definitely help to know from which type your View inherits from.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your view inherits from `MvxActivity` or `MvxFragment` (in case you use fragments). This is required for the view lifetime events to be fired. Also make sure you use `NavigationService` to navigate between views. [See view model lifetime documentation](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/viewmodel-lifecycle) for more details.

Comment: My view inherits from `MvxContentPage<MainViewModel>`. I dug a bit further doing some reproes, and found that updating NuGet packages in the solution caused this. I tried reverting to MvvmCross 5.1.1 (from 5.2 which was the target version after updating NuGet packages), but that did not help. So, I am assuming some other updated caused the Android implementation to go bust, while the iOS implementation works fine. I am still confused as to where to look.

Comment: That is very unusual. I would suggest reporting the problem to MvvmCross GitHub repo